# Unable to access profilePicture JSON parameter in LinkedIn profile response (Java)

Tags: java, linkedin-api

I am trying to retrieve the profilePicture parameter in the LinkedIn liteProfile response. However, for some reason, they return two json objects with the same parameter name (Who even built this API?!).

Response:

```
{
    "firstName": {
        "localized": {
            "en_US": "Damien"
        },
        "preferredLocale": {
            "country": "US",
            "language": "en"
        }
    },
    "lastName": {
        "localized": {
            "en_US": "Roger"
        },
        "preferredLocale": {
            "country": "US",
            "language": "en"
        }
    },
    "profilePicture": {
        "displayImage": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C5103AQEGbbhK9i7Qhw",
        "displayImage~": {
            "paging": {
                "count": 10,
                "start": 0,
                "links": []
            },
            "elements": [ 
               {
                  "identifiers": [
                  {
                     "identifier": "https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C5103AQEGbbhK9i7Qhw/profile-displayphoto-shrink_200_200.....",
                        ....
                  }
               }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

As you may have noticed, in `profilePicture`, there's two params called `displayImage`. One with a `~`. How do I access this from a java pojo class?

My class looks like this:

```
public class LinkedInProfileResponse {

    public FirstName firstName;
    public LastName lastName;
    public ProfilePicture profilePicture;
    public String id;

    public class ProfilePicture {
        public String displayImage;
        public DisplayImage displayImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: What library are you using for creating your POJO from the JSON? There are usually annotations you can use to specify the mapping from JSON property name to POJO field.

Comment: I'm using GSON @tgdavies

Comment: Have you tried `@SerializedName`?

Comment: @tgdavies I haven't tried that. How will it parse the ~ symbol though?

Comment: The parameter is a String, it should handle it.

Comment: That worked! @tgdavies If you can post that as an answer, I can accept it mate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@SerializedName` annotation can be used on a field in your POJO to specify the name of the JSON attribute to be mapped to the Java field.

So in your case:

```
...
@SerializedName("displayImage~)
public DisplayImage displayImage;
...
```